# Using $ symbol in android:name value

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-source

I am trying to understand some piece of code in android. I see

```
<activity
android:name="Settings$DemoRangeActivity"
```

Could some one explain significance or usage of $ symbol in the name. I don't find any activity with name DemoRangeActivity. Is that correct what I am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: @HalimQarroum Thanks for your response. But I am trying to search for DemoActivity but not able to find the inner class in Settings.java

Comment: The name is `DemoRangeActivity` not `DemoActivity`.

Comment: @HalimQarroum Hi, I am working on android source code 4.2.2 and there are some additional functionalities added to Settings folder. The Settings module is implemented as app and its manifest is modified to have new activities. One such class we added is DemoRange.java. I am able to find a separate DemoRange.java which extends SettingsPreferenceFragment. But the manifest as mentioned shows differently.

Comment: @Simon The author edited the activity name afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings$DemoRangeActivity` is a reference to the inner class `DemoRangeActivity` defined in the `Settings` class. If you noticed that this class is referenced in the manifest, but not actually defined in the `Settings` class, the app will crash as soon as this particular class will be opened as an `Activity`.

In the *Settings* application part of the AOSP, and more specifically in the `Settings.java` file, every activities related to the settings app are referenced at the bottom of the file with an empty body. They all extend the `Settings` class. This involves something such as :

```
/*
 * Settings subclasses for launching independently.
 */
public static class BluetoothSettingsActivity extends Settings { /* empty */ }
public static class WirelessSettingsActivity extends Settings { /* empty */ }
...
```

Each of these usually have an associated fragment implemented in a separate source file as you mentioned, which extends the `SettingsPreferenceFragment` class. This is done so that your fragment (implemented in the other file) can be separately launched as an activity. If you watch closely, the `Settings` class is a `PreferenceActivity`.

If you are adding your own fragment to the Settings app, you might want to declare it in the `Settings.java` file as well as in its manifest file. So basically, you'll have a `DemoRange` fragment in a separate file, as well as a `DemoRangeActivity` declared in both `Settings.java` and the manifest file, an example of such a declaration would be :

```
<!-- Demo range settings activity -->
<activity android:name="Settings$DemoRangeActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="com.android.settings.SHORTCUT" />
   </intent-filter>
   <!-- Here is your actual binding between the activity and the fragment -->
   <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
      android:value="com.android.settings.DemoRange" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.TOP_LEVEL_HEADER_ID"
       android:resource="@id/demo_range_settings" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you help me solve the issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769874/android-switchpreference-not-responding-when-selecting-a-preference-setting